# How to optimize ElasticSearch multiple queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I have one index called user_info, under the index there are two types called user and events. Right now I need to query out 200 users and each user with 10 events.
So I did the query as following(sodu script):
for searching user:

```
{size:200,"match:{"user_address":"CA Sf"}}
```

And then I issued 200 quires to Event type:
for search event:

```
{size:10,"term":{"userid":"id1"}}
{size:10,"term":{"userid":"id2"}}
....
{size:10,"term":{"userid":"id200"}}
```

Any idea please to optimize the above queries, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below query:

```
{
"query": {
  "terms": {
     "userid": [
        // list of userId
     ]
  }
},
"aggs": {
  "group By user": {
     "terms": {
        "field": "userId"
     },
     "aggs": {
        "Group By event": {
           "terms": {
              "field": "event_type"
           },
           "aggs": {
              "top10": {
                 "top_hits": {
                    "size": 10
                 }
              }
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query would be slow if you run this for all 200 userIds. You better divide list of userIds into chunks and then run the above query.

Comment: great answer, a following question please, actually I have three event types: talk_event, action_event, history_event. each event should return 10 records base on each userId, should I use multiple search API to combine these types query.

Comment: Sorry, I may confused you, I mean there are three Index _types, such as: user_info/talk_event, user_info/action_event, user_info/history_event. the Index name is user_info.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `terms` queries

something like this

```
{size:200, "terms" : { "userid" : ["id1", "id2", ... ,"id200"]}}
```

Comment: As per the question, there has to be 10 events corresponding to every userId. Providing size 200 doesn't gurantee that each userId will have 10 records. Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: Agreed, if that's really what the op wants your solution is the way to go